# Auto Trim whitespace for optimize reading HTML/JS page

Tags: php, jquery, templates, optimization

I have generated PHP files for cache loading (via file_get_contents() or include() which randomly procedures...) and let's considere this example:

Un-optimized mode or uncached:

What I NOT want to see:

- spaces between `<body>` and `<head>`
- spaces between closed tags: `/>  <script` or `<table> <tr>`

What I WANT to see (optimized way using PHP maybe `PREG_REPLACE`):

- trimed spaces between tags `<body><head>`
- trimed spaces between closed tags: `/><script` or `<table><tr>`

For above full example should be as RESULT such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE><head><link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><title>Title</title><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8'> <meta name="description" content="Description site" /><meta name="keywords" content="keywords, another keywords" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquerymin.js"></script></head><body><div id="center_box"><div id="orderdata"><table></table></div><div id="orderform"><form method="post" action="/frontacp" method="post" action="/frontacp" method="post" action="/frontacp" method="post" action="/frontacp"><div class="logincol"><div class="leftcol"><label for="types_name">Tip proizvoda</label></div><div class="rightcol"><input type="text" name="types_name" /></form></div></div></body></html>
```

Instead BAD (unoptimized usage) of page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE><head>
    <link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8'> <meta name="description" content="Description site" /><meta name="keywords" content="keywords, another keywords" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquerymin.js"></script></head>
    <body><div id="center_box">
        <div id="orderdata">
        <table>

        </table>
        </div>

        <div id="orderform">
        <form method="post" action="/frontacp" method="post" action="/frontacp" method="post" action="/frontacp" method="post" action="/frontacp"><div class="logincol"><div class="leftcol"><label for="types_name">Tip proizvoda</label></div><div class="rightcol"><input type="text" name="types_name"    /></form>    </div>
    </div></body></html>
```

Solutions: PHP example to trim this problem using in properly method and wan't trim spaces inner HTML tags.

Notice: I have done about reading cache and rendering this question would not cover in this area.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$document = preg_replace( '/\n/', '', $document );
$document = preg_replace( '/>\s+</', '><', $document );
$document = preg_replace( '/\s{2,}/', ' ', $document );
```

Bye

Comment: This tested and can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more complex than one might think and it raised a lot of questions here. I took the liberty to find one that seems to have a proper solution:

[minifying-final-html-output-using-regular-expressions-with-codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312349/minifying-final-html-output-using-regular-expressions-with-codeigniter)

(just ignore the reference of CodeIgniter there, since the solution is just a regex)