# Regex: how to uglify HTML without losing formatting in certain tags

Tags: html, regex, formatting, minify, haxe

I am building a static site generator in Haxe. The advantage of having everything static is that you can output the html however you want. I already strip comments from the templates out of the output html using a regexp.

However I was wondering how I could minify the html in the same process. I did a simple split/join on tab/newlines characters, but I quickly found that this doesn't work for content inside pre/code and script tags.

How can I remove newlines and tabs without losing formatting inside pre/code/script tags?

Note; I dont mind to get answers in different coding languages than Haxe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using this regexp

> [Minifying final HTML output using regular expressions with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312349/minifying-final-html-output-using-regular-expressions-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I remove newlines and tabs without losing formatting inside pre/code/script tags?

You can't remove formatting (new lines) without affecting formatting.. that's the whole point of pre and code. You will have to keep them.

If you want to avoid them to be removed in these tags, you will have to write a complete HTML-Parser that understands when a tag is opened or closed. Or use an existing uglifyer.

A simple (maybe not complete) way would be `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(dom)` where you first remove new lines between the DOM-Elements

Comment: MmI mean, how can i remove these characters, but inside these tags.

Comment: You will have to write a complete HTML-Parser that understands when a tag is opened or closed. Or use an existing uglifyer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does it really need to be complete html parser? Cant i just seach for <script or <pre or <code ? The templates are mostly under my own control so there are no weird exceptions.

Comment: Well, if you are sure that there are nowhere `"<code"` in some text or attributes or scripts, then yes. But in future you might not think about this and wonder whey there is an error.

Comment: @MarkKnol Do you need any more help?

Comment: I still don't know how to replace everything outside `<code|pre|script` and `</code|pre|script`. XMLSerializer seems only available in JavaScript context, but everything runs in macro/neko context. There is also no "dom" to be parsed; all html that is generated is in this context a big string.